# How to parse xml tags with space in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, xml-parsing

```
<Messages> <Message activeFrom="2012-05-19T00:00:00+05:30" activeUpto="2012-12-31T00:00:00+05:30" createdById="1" createdByName="admin admin" createdOn="2012-05-19T15:23:56+05:30" description="As per client requirement AASTHA MULTIMEDIA is a multimedia education academy where students can innovatively create new designs with the help of advanced technology in multimedia which consider waterfall methodology.As per client requirement AASTHA MULTI" id="61" imageURL="3c1b77f9-2142-440d-ae8a-d0cbe2769c83.jpg" isActive="T" isTargetedToAffiliation="F" lastModifiedOn="2012-07-06T17:58:09+05:30" messageSubject="Consumer testing working with the wizeowl portal" organizationid="283" organizationImageName="b38e78fd-0f44-4a32-8d6e-35ca47d79dc4.png" organizationname="Biggin Scott" lastModifiedById="1" lastModifiedByName="admin admin"/> <Message activeFrom="2012-09-18T00:00:00+05:30" activeUpto="2012-09-30T00:00:00+05:30" createdById="495" createdByName="Jayul Mehta" createdOn="2012-05-21T15:16:57+05:30" description="test. http://www.google.com" id="62" imageURL="618dae63-9861-4702-add7-fea06cf2f403.png" isActive="T" isTargetedToAffiliation="F" lastModifiedOn="2012-08-30T12:15:09+05:30" messageSubject="test" organizationid="325" organizationImageName="2cc2c83e-144d-4687-b087-ef459ee4e3a1.jpg" organizationname="test org without email and web address" lastModifiedById="1" lastModifiedByName="admin admin"/> </Messages>
```

Here is string which i need to parse... I can get that there are two objects of "Message"... But I can not get the Value in it.

Following method is not being called.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

Please reply for how to parse this type of XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {


   if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Message"]){
         NSString *activeFrom=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"activeFrom"];
         NSString *activeUpto=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"activeUpto"];
         NSString *createdById=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"createdById"];
         NSString *createdByName=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"createdByName"];
         NSString *description=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"description"];

         ....... so on ......

   }



}
```

@Dimple the way you want the value from xml string, you can grab it from the attributeDict parameter passed by delegate method didStartElement. Overwrite the didStartElement method in your code by above snippet. Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but...My attributeDict has 0 key value pairs

Answer (score 1):

Use TBXML to parse XML content..
http://tbxml.co.uk/

or check this tutorial tutorial for NSXML [link](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file/)

Answer (score 0):

use this guide [How to chose the best xml parser...](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project), i found TBXML the best choice in your case